# Writerows gives me a blank csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I made an array called list_of_rows, and looped appending list_of_cells to aforemention list_of_rows

I then attempt to make a csv file by creating one and assigning a variable called writer and well, it gives me a blank file

```
  outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Its supposed to give me a list of rows with cells and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Does it help if you throw a `outfile.close()` at the end?

Comment: Try using `outfile.flush()`.

Comment: Wow, it does work, thanks guys(or gals)!